OAuth integration issue with Nextjs
on the server, here's the setup im using :
const router = require("express").Router();
const {
  register,
  login,
  googleLoginRedirect,
  refreshToken,
  resetPassword,
  setNewPassword,
  verifyResetCode,
} = require("../controllers/auth.controller");
const passport = require("../strategies/google-strategy");

router.route("/login").post(login);
router.route("/register").post(register);
router.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);

router.get(
  "/google/redirect",
  passport.authenticate("google", { session: false }),
  googleLoginRedirect
);

const googleLoginRedirect = (req, res) => {
  const user = req.user;
  const accessToken = generateAccessToken(user._id, user.name);
  const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(user._id, user.name);
  console.log(user)
  res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    sameSite: "strict",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  });

  res.cookie("accessToken", accessToken, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    sameSite: "strict",
    maxAge: 60 * 6 * 60 * 1000,
  });

  res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/chats");
};

const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const User = require("../models/user.model");

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI,
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      try {
        let user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

        if (!user) {
          user = new User({
            googleId: profile.id,
            name: profile.displayName,
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            imageUrl: profile.photos?.[0]?.value || "",
          });
          await user.save();
        }

        done(null, user);
      } catch (error) {
        done(error, false);
      }
    }
  )
);

module.exports = passport;

then on the client side i directly do router.push(googleauthurl) without any axios reqs cuz i think u cant, but on login i need to set the user state using a useAuth context hook, i thought of adding a controller to get the current user which i call on my app main page after authentication but i didnt really like this approach , is there any way or best practice to accomplish the same thing?
For more context: i'm integrating using TanStack Query, here's the login page :
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { z } from "zod";
import { FcGoogle } from "react-icons/fc";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

import { loginSchema } from "@/lib/validation";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { login } from "@/actions/auth";
import { useAuth } from "@/context/AuthContext";

const Login = () => {
  const loginForm = useForm<z.infer<typeof loginSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(loginSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });
  const router = useRouter();
  const { user, setUser } = useAuth();

  const loginMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: login,
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      toast.success("Login successful!");
      setUser({
        id: data.data.id,
        name: data.data.name,
        profilePic: data.data.imageUrl,
      });
      console.log(user)
      router.push("/chats");
    },
    onError: (error: any) => {
      if (error.response?.status === 401) {
        toast.error("Invalid email or password.");
      } else {
        toast.error("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
      }
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof loginSchema>) => {
    console.log(values);
    const toastId = toast.loading("Logging in...");

    loginMutation.mutate(values, {
      onSettled: () => {
        toast.dismiss(toastId);
      },
    });
  };

  const handleGoogleLogin = () => {
    router.push(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth/google`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="size-full h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-y-4 bg-main">
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;

